# Moment of Inertia of Euler's Disc

Tags: rotational-dynamics

I was thinking about the [Euler's disc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Disk) and why its angular velocity increases over time. The conclusion I arrived on is that the gravitational potential energy of the disc gets converted to the rotational kinetic energy (I have assumed there is no translation). But when I tried to write down conservation of energy I had problems with the determining the moment of inertia term of the disc. There are two axis that the disc is spinning about; one is passing perpendicular to the disc and through its centre and the other is perpendicular to the floor. The moment of inertia about central axis is 
$$I=\frac{1}{2}MR^2$$
But I was not able figure out the inertia about the other axis. Also what is the net moment of inertia?

Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: The MMOI across a disk is $ \tfrac{1}{4} M R^2$. Also I think the precession increases while the spin decreases (due to friction).

Comment: @ja72 that is about the x-axis or y-axis. I have clearly states that the disc is rotating about the central axis, i.e. the z-axis.

Comment: https://www.real-world-physics-problems.com/eulers-disk.html

Comment: @ja72 thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See equation (1) of [this paper](http://eulersdisk.com/PRE56610.pdf) describing the total energy of the disk.

> For a disk of radius $R$, mass $m$, and MMOI of $I$, the total energy is $$ E = m g R \sin \alpha + \tfrac{1}{2} I \Omega^2 \sin^2 \alpha $$ where $\alpha$ is the inclination angle w.r.t. horizontal plane, and $\Omega$ the precession rate.

As you can see when the inclination $\alpha$ becomes smaller, the precession must increase in order to maintain the overall energy approximately constant.